# Ethereum extract transactions based on timestamp

Tags: etherscan, timestamp

I am trying to extract all transactions of Ethereum using the eth scan API. But I need transactions for specific time periods only. I tried running the API for all the blocks to try and extract all transactions from the beginning. But, it gave me a 403 error. Can someone please help?

Comment: 403 sounds like didn't pass the apiKey correctly?

Comment: No, I fixed it using sleep function after getting data for every 10 blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it gave me a 403 error

403 sounds like didn't pass the apiKey correctly. **UPDATE**: from your comment above it seems to be a quota issue.

> But I need transactions for specific time periods only.

With ethscan api you can do interval halving to find the start/end block with your matching timestamps.

Or you could use something like https://eth.events. They have all data indexed in a large database and you can use elasticsearch queries to query it.

E.g.

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.eth.events/ethereum/ethereum/mainnet/es/tx/search/ \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $mytoken" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": 1483228800,
              "lte": 1483315200
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 200
}'
```

There is also a Google solution for this: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics

Comment: I am not able to query with timestamp field. I can only do it using the block numbers for the range value. Did the above query work for you?

Comment: Sorry, the query was not correct. I've fixed it. It should just be ``timestamp`` instead of ``blockNumber.timestamp`` (https://docs.eth.events/en/latest/endpoints/tx.html)

Comment: How do I modify this query to get transactions specific to a contract address?